# Add Web API Controller to different assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How can I add Web Api Controller to a different assembly?
I want to separate the web API controllers from my MVC application.

Answer (score 9):

WebApi does that out the box.

The DefaultAssembliesResolver class is the one used to load the assemblies to look for ApiControllers. Here is the source code:

```
  public class DefaultAssembliesResolver : IAssembliesResolver {    
    public virtual ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies() {
      return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
    }
  }
```

The trick is to load your assembly to the AppDomain before the first call to a web.api service.

Call any method of a class in the target assembly or simply load a type from it. Ex:

```
var x = typeof (YourApiControllerInAnotherAssembly);
```

If you're using an older version of WebApi, try implementing IAssembliesResolver and changing the default implementation of it like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), 
                                                   new YourCustomAssemblyResolver());
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue. What do you mean by "Call any method of a class in the target assembly or simply load a type from it". I think this is what's getting me.

Comment: As a workaround, I had to create a dummy class that inherits from my api controllers. The namespace is the target library but the dummy classes reside with my api controllers in the separate library. Hacky but actually works.

Comment: @TruMan1 One thing you can do to check that is to implement and register your IAssembliesResolver exactly the way I showed above and put a break point at the GetAssemblies method. Run the app and when the debugger stops, check if GetAssemblies method is returning the assembly with your controllers too.

Answer (score 3):

- create a new class library project in your solution and add new
  classes that inherit from ApiController.
- you may have to add some extra references to your new project as all the mvc libraries are not included by default.
- in your mvc project, add a reference to the new class library project that contains your api controllers
- build and test

Comment: Clean the bin folder from the web project and then rebuild the solution